# Unable to set to GB keyboard in vino

Tags: kubuntu, keyboard-layout

I have a host running Kubuntu 15.10 using vino to allow remote access. Unfortunately, the keyboard mapping defaults to US when using vino only (it is set to GB in all other cases). Fortunately, in Kubuntu 14.10 and (I think) 15.04, running `setxkbmap gb` got the keyboard mapping to GB (correct for me).

Unfortunately, this no longer works - `setxkbmap gb` reports the right things, but it seems to be lying.

```
$ setxkbmap "gb" && setxkbmap -print -verbose 10
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc101
layout:     gb
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+gb+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc101)
xkb_keymap {
        xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
        xkb_types     { include "complete"      };
        xkb_compat    { include "complete"      };
        xkb_symbols   { include "pc+gb+inet(evdev)"     };
        xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc101)"     };
};
```

That looks right, but it still uses the US keyboard mapping after the command runs.

I then tried setting the keyboard language to "fr", and that reported fr on the output and DID change the keyboard mapping; so `setxkbmap` is at least sometimes fully working.

I suspected some sort of corruption of my keyboard maps, so I nuked the contents of `/var/lib/xkb`. I also had a poke around in `/usr/share/X11/xkb` to see if the gb file looked right, and as far as I can tell it did.

Finally, normal ssh into this box is fine, and using the desktop from a connected keyboard (not VNC) works fine too; both pick up the gb keyboard automatically.

Can anybody suggest what on earth might be going on?

Thank you.